# Which set is this 2 x 6 slope with holes from?

Tags: technic, part-identification, slope

I picked up a bag of loose LEGO at a thrift shop and cannot identify which set this piece comes from:

[image: Unknown Lego Element]

The holes pass all the way through the slope but have small details inside that prevent a standard technic axle from going through:

[image]

If anyone has seen it before, knows which set it comes from or what its purpose is, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE Matthew.  Thanks for the excellent pictures of the part in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a [Fabuland Roof Support Slope, 6 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=787).

[image]

If it's like the similar ones I've seen in Duplo, it probably came pre-assembled into one of these:

[Fabuland Roof Support with Gray Roof Slope without Chimney Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=787c05)

[image]

[Fabuland Roof Support with Red Roof Slope with Chimney Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=787c03)

[image]

[Fabuland Roof Support with Red Roof Slope without Chimney Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=787c01)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. I would not have guessed that and I spent a few hours trying to find it in a database. You have put my mind at ease.